# Terminal has 2 status bar

Tags: macos, terminal

When I launch terminal, I see 2 status bar attached. Normally second status bar should be visible if I open a second tab on the window. However it even appears on the very first tab.
Visual is below: [image]

I have created a second user on my Mac. On this second user, it is just fine. Terminal starts with one status bar.

I don't know what to do, I have searched all over the internet, nothing helpful. Last time this happened, I had to wipe everything and re-install the OS, I don't want to do it now :/

Comment: Surely that's the normal display when you have switched on `View | Show Tab Bar` but only have one tab in the window ?  And the setting is sticky, it will be remembered next time you launch the terminal.

Comment: wow, tell me something I can do for you. you saved me from a burden lasting for years. :)

Comment: Send money, large denomination bank notes not in sequential order.  Send it quickly and don't stop ...

Comment: right away sir 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terminal, select View -> Hide Tab Bar or type <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. That setting is sticky and is used for every new window you launch.